# Multithreading Reading LINES using 3 Threads in VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

Im trying to Read a File Example Output should be
String1
String2
String3

Im using 3 Threads for Example i want to read 1 file this is my Code to start the Threads

```
For i = 0 To 3 - 1
 Dim HTTPFlood As New Threading.Thread(AddressOf TEST)
 HTTPFlood.Start()
 LIST.Add(HTTPFlood)
Next
```

thats what im using to display the output im trying to split the file in 3 peases first and then trying to make it each thread collects another file to make it display right but it gives me something like

String1
String1
String2

```
public sub TEST
thread_connect += 1
thread_file = "C:\Users\msfde\Desktop\b_" + thread_connect + ".txt"
For Each element As String In File.ReadAllLines(thread_file)
console.writeline(element)
next
```

can anyone help me to read the file good like

string1
string2
string3

instead of

string1
string1
string1

i hope someone can help me im siting here 48 hours ive tryed everything to make each thread read another line buts its so hard

Answer (score 0):

First, reading file with thread won't speed things up since you are limited by the hardware. Second, I don't know how thread_connect is created but it doesn't look thread safe. Meaning, it's possible that 2 thread increases thread_connect, create thread_file then both will use the same thread_file as a variable with the same value inside. You need to make it thread safe.

```
Public threadConnect As Integer = 0
Public lockObject As New Object

public sub TEST
    Dim filename As String ' Local variable, threads won't share the same variable 

    SyncLock lockObject ' Lock the thread to make sure they don't access the shared threadConnect variable at the same time
        threadConnect += 1
        filename = "C:\Users\msfde\Desktop\b_" + threadConnect + ".txt"
    End SyncLock

    For Each element As String In File.ReadAllLines(filename)
        console.writeline(element)
    next
```